# Gradle Configuration doesn't work for two groups of config files and dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, logback

I am building a Java project to test performance of log4j and logback. The test codes for these 2 utility are the same via slf4j:

```
package com.boco.logb;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerOneThread {
    public static final long TOTAL_TIMES = 4000 * 1000;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(LoggerOneThread.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 1; i < TOTAL_TIMES; i++) {
            logger.debug("This is a test message. This is another test message.");
        }
        long estimatedTime = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(System.nanoTime()
                - start);
        System.out.println("Write " + TOTAL_TIMES + " logs takes time "
                + estimatedTime + " s.");
    }
}
```

When I add log4j.properties and corresponding jar files ('log4j:log4j:1.2.17' and 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7') into classpath, this program will produces log4j logs. The log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log4j.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %p %c - %m%n
```

While if the logback.xml and corresponding jars ('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2', 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2') are added into classpath, it will produce logback logs. The logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logback.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>logback.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>11</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I tried to build these 2 configuration with Gradle, so I can run them respectively with:

```
gradle run log4j
gradle run logback
```

my build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceSets {
    log4j {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'res/log4j'
        }
        output.dir 'build/classes/log4j'
    }

    logback {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'res/logback'
        }
        output.dir 'build/classes/logback'
    }
}

mainClassName = "com.boco.logb.LoggerOneThread"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
version = '1.0'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    log4jCompile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17', 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7'
    log4jRuntime 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17', 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7'
    logbackCompile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2', 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2'
    logbackRuntime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2', 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2'
}
```

But when I ran `gradle classes`, there were no class files created in build/classes/log4j or build/classes/logback. How to config so I can run log4j and logback respectively? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `classess` tasks only builds the source for default "main" source set which is added by the `Java` plugin. However, when you add a new source set, the `Java` plugin additionally adds a `<sourceSet>Classes` task for each defined source set. Try:

```
$ gradle log4jClasses
```

You can find more information on how this works in the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. "log4jClasses" does work. But why "log4jBuild" and "log4jJar" are "not found in root project ...", while "classes", "build" and "jar" both listed in `Gradle tasks` provided by "java" plugin? I've read Gradle docs about Souce sets, but didn't find any explanations.

Comment: Adding a source set only adds a compile task. How you package your application is for you to decide. You could include these classes in the default jar or create a `Jar` task for each source set.